# get JMSMessageID when use producerTemplate

Tags: apache-camel, jms

In Camel,

```java
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
producerTemplate.sendBody("endpointqueue?includeSentJMSMessageID=true", ExchangePattern.InOnly, body);
```

I would need to get JMSMessageID that is returned from IBM MQ/ActiveMQ. I am looking at exchange values on debug mode but cannot find it. I can only find sessionID. Where is it stored and how to get it?

The [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/jms-component.html) says:

> **includeSentJMSMessageID** - only applicable when sending to jms destination using InOnly. enabling this option will enrich the Camel Exchange with the actual JMSMessageID that was used by the JMS client when the message was sent to the JMS destination.

Is `includeSentJMSMessageID` different than my needs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc says the JMS MessageID is available as header.
So you should be able to return it like this:

```
from("direct:queueMessage")
    .to("jms://myqueue?includeSentJMSMessageID=true")
    .setBody().simple("${header.JMSMessageID}");
```

And then send your message using:

```
String msgId = producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:queueMessage", body, String.class);
```